# Retrieve backlink infos from linked image generated by php

Tags: php, image, trackback

This time ask you this question:

Assuming we have this img ( generated by php ) linked in clients sites

```
<img src="http://mysite.com/genimg.php?id=2" alt=""/>
```

**Is Possible** to get back from the client location some infos!**?** ( es. client url )

PS:

1. don't need something that open
   the entire client page and search for link!
2. don't need something that work just if the link image is
   clicked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can figure out everything from [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) global variable in your **genimg.php**, just as a normal script would.

For example, use $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] to determine the host name from which the user is viewing the current page (in your case, loading the image). See more details in the manual.

Comment: tnx for reply! it helped me! easier than I thought! ;-)
PS: sry i can't vote your answer cause of my low reputation! lol!